# OpenEdge ABL / Progress 4GL Query

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I need help writing this progress query:
    find first a no-lock
      where a.a = variable
      and   a.b = variable2
      and   a.c = variable3
      and ((a.d <> variable4 
      and   a.e <> variable5
      and   a.f <> variable6)
    /* this "or in" is just sudecode for what I want it to do */
      or in (first b no-lock where b.a = variable
      and (b.b = variable7 or b.b = variable8 no-error)))
      no-error.`

The "or in" is the thing I'm having trouble with.

Comment: You'll have to describe more precisely what you mean by 'or in'. Either way, you're trying to find the first table entry of table 'a' with a where-clause, but i don't get the reference to table 'b'. What's supposed to be 'in'?

Comment: I want to check if a.d <> variable... OR there is an item returned from the second statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the kind of statement you want to create, I suggest the following two-step process:

```
find first b no-lock where b.a = variable 
                           and (b.b = variable7 or b.b = variable8) no-error.

find first a no-lock where a.a = variable 
                           and a.b = variable2 
                           and a.c = variable3 
                           and ((a.d <> variable4 and a.e <> variable5 and a.f <> variable6) 
                                 or available b) 
             no-error.
```

Comment: I believe that you will find that: where b.a = v1 and ( b.b = v7 or b.b = v8 ) is more efficient if written as:  where ( b.a = v1 and b.b = v7 ) or ( b.a = v1 and b.b = v8 )

Answer (score 0):

Don't think too much it like  MS SQL query or the general scripting query.

like
 for each test1  no-lock where test1.a = var1 and test1.b = var2 no-error.

same as 
find first test1 no-lock where test1.a = var1 and (test1.b = var2 or test1.c = var3) no-error.  // it gives you only one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the statement you are looking for is 'can-find'.

```
... or can-find(first b where b.a = a.a ...
```